# Javascript: == Operator between number and inline function

Tags: javascript

I was trying to use JS inline functions while using the == but it is not working:

```
function test()
{
    return 1;
}

function test2()
{
    if (1 == test())
    {
        //Works
    }
}

function test3()
{
    if (1 == function () { return 1; })
    {
        // Doesn't work
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible?

Comment: `if (1 == (function () { return 1; })())` If you call the function it matches, but the function itself isn't equal to one.

Comment: FWIW, inlining a function in this situation makes no sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You if condition:

```
1 == function () { return 1; }
```

attempts to compare the number `1` with a *function* (rather than its return value). So it obviously does not match.

Changing it to an **[IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)** like below, will make it pass:

```
1 == (function () { return 1; })()
```

Comment: You don't need the parens around the function expression, having `==` on the LHS is sufficient to make it a function expression rather than a declaration. `1 == function () { return 1; }()`

Comment: @Quentin - Thanks for the info. I've always just used braces around them (primarily just for clarity).

Comment: @Quentin True but it's generally considered best practice to wrap it in parentheses. Better to get them started with a good practice and figure out the reasoning later ;)